# getting path for resource that is a folder not working

Tags: path, ios7, resources

I want to populate my core database initially with some data I've created on the simulator. It worked fine when I had a persistentStore file that I created prior to ios7, but since then I had to modify my core database and therefore have to create new initial data. The problem is now in ios7, in addition to the persistentStore file, there is also a persistentStore-shm and persistentStore-wal file. Because of this, I've used the simulator to make the data I want but now I need to copy the entire StoreContent folder into my app. The problem is, my initial data folder cannot be found. I have my data that I want to be copied in a folder called "InitialCateforyStoreContent" and am using this line of code to find the path to it.

```
 NSString *initialDataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"InitialCategoryStoreContent" ofType:nil];
```

It works fine if I try to find a single file, but it just doesn't work for my directory. Why does it not work and how can I get the path of a directory so I can copy all of its contents to the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/pathForResource%3aofType%3ainDirectory%3a)?

What you're trying to do simply can't be done.

> Returns the full pathname for the resource file identified by the specified name and extension and residing in a given bundle directory.

You can send `ofType: nil`, but:

> If extension is an empty string or nil, the extension is assumed not
>   to exist and the file is the first file encountered that exactly
>   matches name.

You can't return folders using this method.

Comment: I saw that but didn't interpret it as excluding directories as a "file", but I guess it does. Thanks for the confirmation